# Combine an Observable<string> and an Array<Observable<string>> into a single Observable<{string, string[]}>

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have a form that looks something like this:

[image: Form UI]

The `Program Name` and `Description` are a part of a Reactive Form. And the `Feature Image` and `Video(s)` are file inputs.

I have two buttons that submit the form, Save as Draft and Publish. Publish will get enabled if all the fields are filled including both the file inputs. Save as Draft is always enabled and will submit the form.

**On Form Submit:**
I check if there is a Feature Image. If there is one, I upload it to a Firebase Storage Bucket. I apply the same check for Videos. If there is/are any video(s), I upload them one by one to the Firebase Storage Bucket. Here's the code for the same:

```
let featureImageUrl$: Observable<string>;
const videoUrls$: Observable<string>[] = [];
// Check if featureImageToUpload was uploaded
if (this.featureImageToUpload) {
  featureImageUrl$ = this.fileService.upload(`content/programs/images/${this.utils.generateRandomString()}`, this.featureImageToUpload);
}

// Check if video(s) was/were uploaded
if (this.videosToUpload) {
  this.utils.range(this.videosToUpload.length).forEach(fileIndex => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    const videoUrl$ = this.fileService.upload(`content/programs/videos/${this.utils.generateRandomString()}`, this.videosToUpload[fileIndex]);
    videoUrls$.push(videoUrl$);
  });
}
```

`this.fileService.upload` is just a method that returns an `Observable<string>` essentially wrapping the Download URL of the file that was uploaded.

`this.utils.range` is just a method that returns an Array of numbers based on the length. so if the length is 4, then it will return `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

### The issue:

I want to create an `Observable` which I can subscribe to, to get an Object with a structure like this:

```
{
  featureImageUrl: 'DOWNLOAD URL FOR THE FEATURE IMAGE' || null // null in case the file wasn't uploaded;
  videos: [
    'DOWNLOAD URL FOR VIDEO 1',
    'DOWNLOAD URL FOR VIDEO 2',
    'DOWNLOAD URL FOR VIDEO 3',
    'DOWNLOAD URL FOR VIDEO 4',
    ...
  ] || null // null in case the video(s) were not uploaded;
}
```

### Things I've tried so far:

I could use `forkJoin` like this:

```
forkJoin(...videoUrls$, featureImageUrl$)
  .subscribe(downloadUrls => {
    console.log(downloadUrls);
  });
```

And then extract the video download urls based on the length of `videoUrls$` and then create my Object accordingly. But I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing this.

I also tried using `Observable.create` but couldn't wrap my head around it for this specific use case.

With suggestions from [Buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801495/buggy), I also tried this:

```
forkJoin(forkJoin(videoUrls$), featureImageUrl$)
  .pipe(
    map(([videoUrls, featureImageUrl]) => ({videoUrls, featureImageUrl}))
  );
```

It works perfectly fine in case both the Feature Image and Videos are selected. But if I just select Feature Image not don't select any videos, the subscription never reaches.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-eg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your reference.

Comment: `forkJoin(forkJoin(videoUrls$), featureImageUrl$)
  .pipe(
    map(([videoUrls, featureImageUrl])=>({videoUrls, featureImageUrl}))
    )`
does it fit well?

Comment: @Buggy, thanks for the comment. Let me check. :)

Comment: Okay. So it works fine when both the Feature Image file and the videos are selected and then submitted. But doesn't work when on of them is not selected. In the later case, its stuck forever I'll update the question with this approach though. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @SiddAjmera it seems like `featureImageUrl$` you haven't assigned any value as such, can you try it to assign initial value like `let featureImageUrl$: Observable<string> = of('');`, which would atleast suffice the data stream to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complementing the approach suggested by [Buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801495/buggy)**

There are currently 2 issues in your approach

1. You are not initializing the `featureImageUrl$` with a default `Observable` value. When `forkJoin` receives a non *observable-like* value as one of its args (in this case `undefined`), it will raise an exception.
2. When no video is selected, you pass an **empty list** to the inner `forkJoin`. As `forkJoin` does not know how to deal with an empty list of streams, it will never emit a value.

A solution would be for example the following:

```
let featureImageUrl$: Observable<string> = of(null);
let videoUrls$: Observable<string[]> = of(null);
if (this.featureImageToUpload) {
  featureImageUrl$ = this.fileToStream(this.featureImageToUpload);
}

if (this.videosToUpload) {
  videoUrls$ = forkJoin(Array.from(this.videosToUpload)
    .map(file => this.fileToStream(file)));
}

forkJoin(videoUrls$, featureImageUrl$)
  .pipe(
    map(([videoUrls, featureImageUrl]) => ({ videoUrls, featureImageUrl }))
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log({data});
  });

....

private fileToStream(file: File): Observable<string> {
   return this.fileService
     .upload(`content/programs/videos/${this.utils.generateRandomString()}`, file)
}
```

You can see it working in [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-eg-e6dfbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)